# How to limit area of Random.onUnitSphere when instantiating?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using `Random.onUnitSphere` to randomly select a spawning location in a 3d radius of 50 which it instantiates my objects randomly anywhere in the sphere.

Now my question is how to I control this randomness on a specific location in the sphere?

For example, imagine when calling `Random.onUnitSphere`, the center is the target as all the objects go to the center.

What if I only want use the top left of the sphere to be used in instantiating? And then change that top left of the sphere to do the bottom pole of the sphere?

```
object.transform.position = (Random.onUnitSphere * 50) + transform.position;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What if I only want use the top left of the sphere to be used in instantiating?

Simply get a random point on sphere and adjust the sign of the axes to be in the desired hemisphere.  Here we make use of `Math.Abs`.

MSDN has this to say on `Math.Abs`

> Returns the absolute value of a specified number

So by using `Math.Abs()` we ensure that all values are positive.  For the `x`-axis this will mean that all values are positive or "the right hand side".  By simply applying a minus sign (`-`) in front of `Math.Abs` we ensure that the final result will be all negative or "left".

The `y` axis is easy.  We just use `Math.Abs` and this will result in all values being positive, which in the default co-ordinate system will be *"top"*.

```
var P = Random.onUnitSphere * 50;
P.x = -Math.Abs(P.x); // force left
P.y = Math.Abs (P.y); // force top
```

> And then change that top left of the sphere to do the bottom pole of the sphere?

```
// continuing from above...
// move to bottom pole
object.transform.position = P + transform.position.
```

### Tell me more

- *[Math.Abs Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.abs?view=netframework-4.7.2)*

Comment: To be better understand your code, can you explain how `P.x = -Math.Abs(P.x);` would force `Random.onUnitySphere` to only `force left` on its random instantiating